# AG Grid table data copy to clipboard not working in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, copy, ag-grid, clipboard

I tried to copy the ag grid table to clipboard   using class name when click on button but it was not working.

```
 copyTable() {       
            var tblDat= document.getElementsByClassName('tableStats');
            tblDat.select();
            document.execCommand('copy'); 
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `document` to select the data, AG Grid provides [clipboard](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-grid/clipboard/) functionality to help with this.

Change your function to:

```
copyTable()
{
    this.gridApi.selectAll();
    this.gridApi.copySelectedRowsToClipboard();
}
```

This is will first select all the rows, then copy them to the clipboard.